# I have 400+ bookmarks without titles (have 'untitled' for a title.) Is there an easy fix?

Tags: bookmarks, metadata, google-bookmarks, title

For a while I've used Opera's custom search as a tool to save urls Google Bookmarks. But my custom search never saved titles.

Now, I've imported these to Diigo and they all have (untitled) for a title. Is there any tool I can use to go and fetch titles for my bookmarks?